In rviz2, when the XY value is large, the marker is not displayed correctly
In rviz2, when the XY value is large, the marker is not displayed correctly.
I am working on autonomous driving positioning. When I convert the latitude and longitude information into UTM coordinates, because the converted coordinate x and y values ​​are relatively large, I find that the converted pose arrows and axis are not displayed properly in RVIZ, and I cannot judge whether the converted position is correct. How can I solve this problem?



